# iPhone app to access an application on windows server

Tags: iphone, windows, windows-server-2008, guptateamdeveloper, centura

I want to create an iPhone app to be able to access and read reports on a 
program.exe that installed in windows server ,, the program.exe is written by centura windows SQL .

the server already online

what the steps I should do ?

Does remote desktop app from Microsoft can do this task or not and if there is another app can do it , please tell me  ?

notice: I already have some experience in programming but in Android only

Comment: What are the functionalities you are planning to implement in program.exe ( written in centura) ?

Comment: I'm just thinking to make a button that shows the report that the manager  want to see via his iPhone mobile by using  remote desktop connection app in iPhone ,, but i'm asking if there is another way better than this or at least another app that can make this connection instead of remote desktop app from Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Check out  [Gupta ( Centura ) TD Mobile here.](http://www.opentext.com/what-we-do/products/specialty-technologies/opentext-gupta-development-tools-databases/opentext-gupta-td-mobile) 
  Easy to programme ( can be very simple or very complex ) , multi platform , multi connectivity. 
Offline capable applications:
 If you need to use your app in areas without network reception you can leverage the multi-page offline mode including local data storage.
See the 'Features' tab in particular.